# What does the phrase "courtesy of" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "courtesy of" mean in the following sentence from the description of a game:

> Here are five favorites, **courtesy of** the game studio's CEO and
> executive producer.

Does the said phrase simply mean "mentioned by" here?

For some context, the text quotes the producer's words in the description of the favorites in the sentences that follow the quoted sentence. The description of each favorite character contains the words told by the producer.

Answer (score 2):

If you acquire something, or are allowed to do something, *by courtesy of* a particular person, it's a rather formal way of saying that that person has had the courtesy to give you the thing or the permission (has been polite enough to do so).

In your example, the writer has used the formal phrase in a mildly humorous way to indicate that the producer has kindly provided a list of their favourites.

Answer (score 1):

"Courtesy of" simply indicates a source. The sentence could be re-written as"Here are five favorites from the game studio's CEO and executive producer." and the meaning would be pretty much identical except perhaps for the original being seen as a bit pretentious.